# How can i position an a div with javascript in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I need to move a div with javascript. i've tried offsetTop/Left and I've tried style.top/left. but it doesnt work. style.top/left works in IE but not safari

```
document.getElementById('links_safari').offsetTop= 20;
document.getElementById('links_safari').offsetLeft = 150;
```

Comment: Have you set position: absolute;?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is tagged with jQuery, so using jQuery, I would suggest changing the margin CSS property.

```
$('#links_safari').css("margin-top", 20);
$('#links_safari').css("margin-left", 150);
```

Comment: just to note, `$('#links_safari').css({"margin-top": 20, "margin-left": 150});` would be more performant.